# Angular 6 waiting for Observable

Tags: angular

I have the below typescript code.

I tried to make the packageFiles method an Observable so I can wait until it's done before I move on. But somethings not right?

```
packageFiles(): Observable<any> {

  var filesToSend = [];

  //Loop through files
  this.files.forEach(f => {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      //
      var fileForUpload = new FileForUpload();
      var encodedString = window.btoa(<string>reader.result);
      fileForUpload.FileValue = encodedString;
      fileForUpload.FileName = f.name;
      fileForUpload.FileType = f.type;

      //
      filesToSend.push(fileForUpload);

      console.log(filesToSend);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(f);

  });

  return of(filesToSend);
}
```

this method calls this then:

```
uploadFiles() {

  var response = this.packageFiles()
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log("data");
      console.log(data);
    },
    error => {

    }
  );
}
```

Comment: While the guys that answered your question figured out by themselves what "something is not right" is supposed to mean, you should be more precise here about what "something" is.

Comment: Your question is to vague. What is the current behavior? what is the expected behavior? Provide a more concrete problem/description and preferably a minimal reproduction. of the perceived issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're synchronously returning an observable of an empty array here, which isn't what you want to do. You need to make sure you first collect the data and then emit on an observable (`of` emits immediately and then completes).

Let's assume for a second that you only had a single `file`. In this case, closest to your code would be using a `Subject`:

```
packageFiles(): Observable<FileForUpload> {
  const result$ = new Subject<FileForUpload>();
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {
    const fileForUpload = new FileForUpload();
    // … do your stuff …

    result$.next(fileForUpload);
    result$.complete();
  };

  // …

  return result$;
}
```

However, this returns a hot observable, and likely it'd be better here to return a cold observable instead:

```
packageFiles(): Observable<FileForUpload> {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      const fileForUpload = new FileForUpload();
      // … do your stuff …

      observer.next(fileForUpload);
      observer.complete();
    };

    // …
  });
}
```

Now you just need to generalize this to multiple files. Let's rename this into `packageFile` and pass the file as an input:

```
packageFile(file: File): Observable<FileForUpload> {
  // …
}
```

Then we can write the actual function as

```
packageFiles(): Observable<FileForUpload[]> {
  return forkJoin(...this.files.map(file => this.packageFile(file)));
}
```

… which you can now use by calling

```
this.packageFiles().subscribe(filesToUpload => { /* … */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing into `filesToSend` at the time your `reader.onload` is called, which does not happen at the time you iterate over your files. Naturally your `filesToSend` is an empty array at the time when you are constructing your observable via `of`. Calling subscribe will directly cause the subject to emit the empty array.

Instead, you should create a subject on which you call `next()` everytime load is complete.